# Git init на существующих файлах и сравнить с удалённым репозиторием

Tags: git, repository

Есть удалённый репозиторий (на битбаскете). Есть компьютер (удалённый сервер, не суть важно), где находится тот же проект, но с некими изменениями. Требуется создать на данном сервере репозиторий, и далее я хочу командой `git status` увидеть изменённые относительно репы локальные файлы. Делаю `git init`, `git remote add origin URL`, `git fetch`, `git status`, но получаю красный список всех локальных файлов/каталогов и сообщение `nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)`.

Если добавить файлы путём `git add .`, то все они становятся зелёными и непонятно что делать дальше (комитить их явно ошибка). Подскажите, как грамотно синхронизировать существующие локальные файлы с удалённым репозиторием?

Comment: Поправка: "на битбакете" (ведро, не корзина).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приципе правильно сделано, за одним исключением.

`git status` показывает изменения относительно текущего коммита.

Нужно чтобы текущим стал коммит из `origin`.

Но `git checkout` делать нельзя, т.к. он перетрет локальные файл.

Нужно сделать `git reset --mixed origin/master`

`reset` изменит положение вашей активной ветки (вероятно master) на тот же коммит, что и origin/master, а параметр `--mixed` заставит при этом не затронуть локальные файлы.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `git init`, `git remote add origin URL`, `git fetch` и после `git reset --soft origin/master`? Он выводит список всех файлов с пометкой что они удалены, и далее листинг каталога проекта с пометкой что файлы не добавлены

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду это. Но перепутал soft и mixid. Можете сделать reset --mixed повер текущего результат. Поправил ответ.